# Symfony and doctrine stuck with complex database

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am a bit stuck with doctrine. We are using a PostgreSQL database with multiple schemas. But Doctrine doesn't seem to support correctly multiple schemas. So we decide to create foreign table on a new database with a single public schema. It does not work because there is no primary keys. So we tried with view, but view doesn't have primary key either. How should we do?

I got another issue concerning primary keys. Apparently doctrine doesn't support primary key composed of 2 primaries from other tables. This is one of the basic functionality of a relational database. Is this normal?

The feeling I get with Doctrine is that we have to build our database in function of the website (or Doctrine). So the database is pretty much dependent of the website.

Comment: Apparently, multiple schema work with Doctrine but the reverse engineering tool doctrine:mapping:import does not make his job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not false that using Doctrine implies to design DB being aware of Doctrine.

Multiple PK : prefer an AUTO_INCREMENT id, and a composed unique index, this is Doctrine philosophy...

There was a trick for multiple DB joins, available on MySQL, PostGre seems to allow it :  http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/cross-database-joins.html

> This will only work if your database supports foreign keys and joins
>   across databases